# Derivative of $trace(|A|)$ with respect to $A$

Tags: matrices

What is the derivative of $trace(|A|)$ with respect to $A$ ?
where:
$|A|$ represents absulote value of $A$ 
and $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix

$\mathbf{Or}$

What is the derivative of $trace(A\  .* \ A)$ with respect to $A$ ?
$A\  .* \ A$ represents elementwise production of $A$

Comment: Is $A$ real or complex ?

Comment: @Astyx, $A$ is real

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locally $g:A\mapsto |A|$ is linear. Therefore $d(Tr\circ g)_A(H) = Tr(JH)$ where $J$ is the diagonal matrix giving the signs ($\pm 1$) of the diagonal coefficient (if they are 0, it's not differentiable).

Comment: What I understand, if for example, $A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1\\ 3 & -1  \end{bmatrix}\ $then $\  \frac{\partial trace(|A|)}{\partial A}= trace \left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1  \end{bmatrix}\right) = 0$ <br/>
Is it right?

Comment: Not quite, ${\partial \operatorname{trace}(|A|)\over \partial A}(H) = \operatorname{trace}(JH) = h_{1,1} - h_{2,2}$ where $J$ is the matrix you wrote on the right.

Comment: Excuse me, what is $H$?

Comment: Any $2\times 2$ matrix. The differential of a function taking a matrix as variable is a linear operator (whiches variable I chose to denote $H$), not a number.